# Function Distance is positive

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $U⊂\mathbb{R}^N$ be an open set,let $K⊂U$ be a compact set,and let $f:U→\mathbb{R}$ be a function of class $C^1$.

Prove that $R := \operatorname{dist}(K,∂U) > 0$ (note that $+∞ > 0$).

If it was a specific function then i would do the calculation and prove it is bigger than $0$. I am not sure how to generalize this to the function of $C^1$.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst It is not true that if two sets have no points in common then  the distance between them is $>0$.  You have to prove that the  distance is attained.

Comment: i think your right, thanks!

Comment: It is unclear to me what the role of the function $f$ is in your question. $dist(K,\partial U)$ does not depend on $f$.